# Template class constructor takes instance of template class

Tags: c++, templates

I have a situation as follows:

```
Class Bar {
...
}

template <class T>
class Foo {
public:
  ...
  Foo(Foo<Bar> bar) {
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

So one of the constructors of class Foo can take an element of class Foo parameterized by Bar. This is all fine until I instantiate something of class Foo parameterized by Bar where this constructor is interpreted as a copy constructor which isn't what I want. I'm wondering how I can have a constructor taking such an element without interfering with the copy constructor. For example I can do this:

```
template <class T>
class Foo {
public:
  ...
  Foo(Foo<Bar> bar, int unused) {
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

And it works fine because now the constructor doesn't conflict with the copy constructor. Is there a standard way to deal with this problem?

Comment: Are C++11 solutions valid? This (I believe) can be easily solvable with C++11 in a clean way, but you will have to resort to hacks in C++03

Comment: Why exactly does it matter?  What side effect of this are you running into?

Comment: @Wug: For starters you cannot have a copy constructor that takes the argument by value, so it will fail to compile.

Comment: Can you work around it by passing a pointer?

Comment: Did you try making the constructor explicit?

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas c++11 is fine

Comment: @NicolasArroyo making the constructor explicit doesn't change anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your class template doesn't need to declare a copy constructor (in the general case), you can declare the constructor as

```
Foo(Foo<Bar> const& bar);
```

which will be a converting constructor in general and a copy constructor for `Foo<Bar>`. Other specializations will use an implicitly declared copy constructor where applicable.

Otherwise, making a constructor a template ensures that it's not a special member. That being said, care has to be taken for that constructor not to interfere with the copy constructor. It's not nice, but you can do this:

```
template<typename U>
Foo(U bar, typename boost::enable_if<boost::is_same<U, Foo<Bar> > >::type* = 0);
```

This is a constructor that is not a copy constructor, and will only ever be used when passed arguments of type `Foo<Bar>`. Do note that due to the rules of overload resolution, the copy constructor of `Foo<Bar>` will be preferred over this constructor.

---

The preceding is for C++03. Here's a simple C++11 solution:

```
template<int = 0>
Foo(Foo<Bar>);
```

Comment: Could you explain the c++11 solution? I don't have access to Boost but c++11 is fair game in my environment.

Comment: @dschatz: A templated constructor is never a copy constructor. Adding the *unused* template argument makes this particular constructor not a template. Luc, does this really work (i.e. does the syntax at the call site not change? can this be used as an implicit conversion?) I was going to suggest something in the lines of `template <typename T, typename _ = typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T,Bar>>::type> Foo( Foo<T> )` (i.e. use SFINAE on a defaulted argument)

Comment: @dschatz The constructor is made a template so it's never considered to be a copy constructor. This means that it can be declared to take `Foo<Bar>` even when instantiated for a `Foo<Bar>` specialization. Furthermore, for `Foo<Bar>` the copy or move constructor will be preferred over that constructor due to the rules of overload resolution (a non-template is preferred to a template where applicable).

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas The constructor is callable, yes. I can't say if it really works because I don't know which constructor the OP wants to be used in e.g. `Foo<Bar> f; auto copy = f;`.

Comment: @LucDanton: I feel that the C++11 solution you propose won't allow this code: `Foo<Bar> fb; Foo<int> fi(fb);` but I have not tested.

Comment: I only want this constructor to be used explicitly. Does this template constructor let me still use the template of the class (T) in my example?

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas [?](http://liveworkspace.org/code/a0afe124ab935cc013b5fd9e964eccbc)

Comment: @dschatz Can you clarify (and ideally put those in your question)? If you want to mark the constructor `explicit`, go ahead. And yes, `T` is in scope inside the constructor. There is no reason it shouldn't be (e.g. shadowing the parameter is not allowed).

Comment: @LucDanton: I was not sure whether you would have to explicitly ask for the template which is not really doable for a constructor. I see it works :)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas This rests on the fact that template parameters that end up using their default are just as good as deduced parameters when it comes to overload resolution. In fact the whole process of finding out the template parameters takes place before overload resolution.

Comment: Sorry, I am a c++ newbie. I've never seen templated constructors. What aspect of this requires c++11? Also this solution works because the templated constructor cannot be used as a copy constructor?

Comment: @dschatz It's not allowed to use default template parameters for *function* templates in C++03. (*Class* templates are however.) The crux of your problem was that `Foo(Foo<Bar>);` declares a copy constructor in the case of the `Foo<Bar>` specialization, and those are not allowed to take a parameter by value (plus if you declare/define a copy constructor elsewhere that's another issue). That this constructor cannot ever be called for the `Foo<Bar>` specialization is an artifact of overload resolution and not really related to the trick.

Comment: What if I want to be able to have both a copy constructor and this constructor for Foo<Bar>? Is there any clean way to do this?

Comment: @dschatz The C++11 solution works as is. However only the copy constructor will ever be called. If this isn't what you want I think you'll need to use an explicit total specialization of `Foo<Bar>` as a last resort.

Answer (score 0):

This is in fact not a valid copy constructor as copy constructors should follow one of the following four formats:

```
MyClass( const MyClass& other );
MyClass( MyClass& other );
MyClass( volatile const MyClass& other );
MyClass( volatile MyClass& other );
```

In order to have everything working as expected pass your parameter as a pointer:

```
Foo(Foo<Bar>* bar) {
    // Logic
}
```

If you pass it by value you can very well create an infinite loop if your logic mimics a copy constructor.

Comment: This solution will work but is effectively equivalent to my int unused solution. And I guess my unused int is safer and won't prevent some compiler optimizations like this one will.

Comment: @dschatz You were asking for an alternative after all. If you like your solution better than the alternative you should absolutely use it.